# Angular - ngFor Performance cause of complex observables

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, angular2-observables

I have written a contract template builder in Angular 5. The client should be able to create/edit its own contract templates by a more or less simple interface. The contract templates than can be used to generate contracts.

To make this work, I have three different data streams.

1. **Template Blocks ->** Its one paragraph of the contract
2. **Inputs ->** Dynamic content of the contract.
3. **Actions ->** They are holding all kind of complexity between the static template blocks and the dynamic inputs

The three main actions are:

1. **Show block** -> If the condition of the action matches, then a template block should be displayed
2. **Show input** -> Inputs can be nested. So when the condition of the action matches, then another input should get displayed
3. **Show text** -> By a placeholder syntax, you can set a position in one or multiple template blocks to print the value of one input.

As I have these three streams as highest level I have a `contract$` stream as BehaviorSubject. This `contract$` stream has three different streams as BehaviorSubject: `inputs$`, `templateBlocks$` and `actions$`.

All operations get executed to one of these four BehaviorSubject. This is also the structure how the API requires the data to create or edit a contract template.

Until this point, it is working as expected...But to visualize this in the contract template builder I need another data structure. That's why I created two streams which are watching for the data of `inputs$`, `templateBlocks$` and `actions$`.

For the inputs, I need to have the inputs nested. So I created a stream `nestedInputs$` which gets the data from `Observable.combineLatest(this.inputs$, this.actions$)` and loops through all inputs, checks if the input is a target of any "Show input" - action and if it is, it creates a nested input structure.

```
{
    config: {the original input config object},
    children: [{
        config: {the original input config object},
        children: []
    }]
}
```

For the template blocks, I need to know which template block is restricted by which input, to visualize the connections. Therefore I combined `Observable.combineLatest(this.inputs$, this.templateBlocks$, this.actions$)` and I´m looping through the template blocks to get the connected input by the action if there is one for this template block. The structure then is

```
{
  config: {the original template block config object},
  restrictedBy: {the connected input config object}
}
```

To change content in the template block I´m using the [Froala WYSIWYG Editor](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor). That means on every template block I´m creating a new editor instance.

It works great until a contract gets bigger. On every action i execute on one of the three main streams `inputs$`, `templateBlocks$` and `actions$` (e.g. adding new input, adding nested input, creating new template block, connecting input with template block or adding input placeholder to template block) it seems like it´s replacing all elements from the three streams and it is not just changing the elements which have changed. Instead, it is again creating all DOM elements again and that's why for bigger contracts it takes several seconds on every update.

I hope I was able to explain my project and the problem I have with it.

Is there any that by the Angular ngForOf-Loop to just replace the elements which have changed or how could I improve my application in another way?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're after at all, maybe try including a lot more code or even a plunkr. But just a shot in the dark here, ngFor performance can be greatly improved by adding a trackBy clause like this (if you had an array items which each had a unique identifier): let item of items; trackBy: id

Comment: @bryan60 trackBy in angular 2 only accepts a function, so this doesn't work.

Comment: right, mixed my angulars up... just pass a function like this then (index, item) => item.id

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was exactly what I was looking for. I didn´t know that it has that massive impact on performance.